# basic multithreading in C# with lists

Tags: c#, multithreading

When you new up a new list in C# in multiple threads, does each thread get its own instance of a list?

So my code looks similar to this:

```
List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();

public void Method(List<List<Batch>> batches) {
    Parallel.ForEach(batches, parallelOptions, (batch, state) => CalculateAndAddToList(batch))
}

private void CalculateAndAddToList(List<Batch> batch) {
 //Some computations
    var localItems = new List<Item>();
    foreach(var b in batch) {
        //Computations of newItems
        localItems.AddRange(newItems);
    }
    _items.AddRange(items);
}
```

I will randomnly get an error that says: "Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds." at the line that says: "localItems.AddRange(newItems)". Since each thread is newing up its own list instance of localitems, I figured other threads wouldn't be changing it, so why am getting that error on that line?

I figured I'd need a lock around "_items.AddRange(items)" since multiple threads access and change the shared field "_items", but I have yet to get a threading error to throw on that line.

Answer (score 5):

It's fine for each thread to have it's own list. The problem you are seeing stems from this line:

```
_items.AddRange(items);
```

is potentially being called from two threads at the same time. `List<T>` is not thread-safe. Use a threadsafe container, such as `ConcurrentBag<T>`, or better still, restate your problem using PLINQ, and allow the framework to safely gather your results for you. You could probably save on quite a lot of code by avoiding partitioning your source data into batches and stating your transformation in parallel linq. It does all of this for you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/28/9648672.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Since `List<T>` isn't thread safe, you'd need to lock before calling `AddRange` on the list:

```
private void CalculateAndAddToList(List<Batch> batch) {
 //Some computations
    var localItems = new List<Item>();
    foreach(var b in batch) {
        //Computations of newItems
        localItems.AddRange(newItems);
    }

    lock(_items)
        _items.AddRange(items);
}
```

A better approach would be to use one of the overloads of `Parallel.ForEach` which accepts local state, and then add the items at the end.  The basic process is covered in [my blog post on the subject](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/).

Alternatively, this appears like could be handled via PLINQ query using `SelectMany`:

```
_items = batches.AsParallel()
                .SelectMany(batch => batch) // Flatten List<List<T>> into List<T>
                .SelectMany(b => ComputeNewItems(b)) // Compute new items, and flatten results                    
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried putting a lock on _items which doesn't stop the error from being thrown on the line "localItems.AddRange(newItems)". I am wondering why I am getting such an error on the local list.